# C# file apparently does not contain the type/namespace I created, even though it does

Tags: c#, dll, build, namespaces, assemblies

I'm having a really annoying issue where a class I added to our codebase works properly on my machine and when I make a debug build...but when I use our build cycle server to make an official build, the build fails. The error says that the type or namespace name 'EventLogger' could not be found. It asks me if I am missing a using directive or an assembly reference. But I'm not. When I go to compile, everything works and there are no errors. It complains about this issue in a file called TestTemplate even though as far as I can see, I have all the proper using directives and there are no missing assembly references. Please advise.

When I look at the solution file and project file for the package in question, I don't see any changes. Should I be seeing changes? Should they be committed to the build server alongside the files I added/worked on?

Comment: Are you certain the project and solution files are checked in as well?

Comment: Pretty certain, but I will double check. I only need to check in the project file for the package where I added the new class file, right? And the entire solution file? No other project files?

Comment: Your machine does one thing. The build machine does another. Therefore the machines are configured differently. List all the ways in which they are configured differently. Then find which of those is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @HandleThatError you need to make sure the build server has ALL of the necessary files to build properly. Than means they need to be checked in AND are being retrieved by the build server.

Comment: Another way to check this would be to do a fresh clone of the repo on your machine and see if that can build.

Comment: I just experimented with running builds after adding only 1 file at a time. It builds correctly until I shelve the TestTemplate file. That's when the error comes back. So I know that the class I added isn't breaking the build...maybe the package that contains TestTemplate is busted. I'll have to look at it more, but I wonder what could be the problem. :(

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus...someone or some THING removed the package I worked on from the appropriate solution. I re-added it and now I'm rebuilding. I think that is the problem...but then again, if that was the problem then why did it work locally?!?!